# Почему выводится итоговое несколько раз?

Tags: ассемблер, nasm, sasm

Пишу на nasm и итоговое выводится несколько раз, пробовал дебажить ничего не понял. В чем причина ?

```
%include "io.inc"

section .data
array: dd 1, 4, 2 , -1 , 5

global CMAIN
section .text
CMAIN:
    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging
    PRINT_STRING "Исходный"
    NEWLINE
    call print
    mov ECX, 0
floop:
    mov EDX, ECX
    call sloop
floopd:
    cmp ECX, 4
    je done
    inc ECX
    jmp floop
sloop:
    mov EAX, [array+ECX*4]
    mov EBX, [array+EDX*4]
    cmp EAX, EBX
    jle ife
    mov [array+ECX*4],EBX
    mov [array+EDX*4],EAX
ife:
    cmp EDX, 4
    je floopd
    inc EDX
    jmp sloop
done:
    PRINT_STRING "Итоговый"
    NEWLINE
    call print
    NEWLINE
    ret 0

print:
    mov EBP, 0
hloop:
    PRINT_DEC 1, [array+EBP*4]
    NEWLINE
    cmp EBP, 4
    je printend
    inc EBP
    jmp hloop
printend:
    ret 0
```

Вывод:

```
Исходный
1
4
2
-1
5
Итоговый
-1
1
2
4
5

Итоговый
-1
1
2
4
5

Итоговый
-1
1
2
4
5

Итоговый
-1
1
2
4
5

Итоговый
-1
1
2
4
5

Итоговый
-1
1
2
4
5
```

Comment: Что именно итоговое выводится несколько раз? Я после вывода "Итоговый" вижу цикл вывода массива из 4 элементов. Он в конце и выводится.

Comment: @insolor в sasm компилирую и получаю вывод исходное-массив и 5 раз итоговое-массив, хотя по коду такое не должно быть

Comment: Посмотрите еще раз в код, с какой строки по какую у вас цикл я написал. И работает именно так как у вас в коде написано.

Comment: @insolor написал, что выводит. Просто вывод массива не находится в цикле и я не могу понять почему он выводится несколько раз

Comment: Вы вызываетe `call sloop` а при `ret` код и возвращается на круги своя. Вы возврашаетесь с помощью `je floopd` а надо делать `RET`. Ну или `Jump sloop` без `call`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Правильный код:

```
%include "io.inc"
section .data
array: dd 1, 4, 2, -1, 5, 7, 3 ,4 ,5 ,6
SIZE: dd 9
section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    mov ebp, esp; for correct debugging
    call print
    mov eax, 0
cmain_floop:
    mov ebx, eax
cmain_sloop:
    mov ecx, [array+ebx*4]
    mov edx, [array+eax*4]
    cmp ecx, edx
    jge cmain_endif
    mov [array+eax*4],ecx
    mov [array+ebx*4],edx
cmain_endif:
    cmp ebx, [SIZE]
    je cmain_endsloop
    inc ebx
    jmp cmain_sloop
cmain_endsloop:
    cmp eax, [SIZE]
    je cmain_endfloop
    inc eax
    jmp cmain_floop
cmain_endfloop:
    call print
    ret
print:
    PRINT_STRING "Array"
    NEWLINE
    mov eax, 0
print_loop:
    PRINT_DEC 1, [array+eax*4]
    NEWLINE
    cmp eax, [SIZE]
    je print_endloop
    inc eax
    jmp print_loop
print_endloop:
    NEWLINE
    ret 0
```